# In Mozilla Firefox browser, when we click on reload current page icon on the address bar, a blank page is shown

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, extjs, browser

Our product supports IE and Mozilla Firefox, when I login to our Element Manager UI, in mozilla firefox, when clicked on the reload current page icon on address bar, I am redirected to a blank page. After that I have to click on adress tab and hit enter for reloading. Redirecting to blank page does not happen when I do F5 or click on address tab and hit enter, It happens only when I click on the reload current page icon on the address bar.

When I click on the reload current page icon, I get a pop up saying "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." I then have to click Resend and then it takes me to blank page.

This happens only once, second time if I click on the relaod current page icon, I dont see the pop up and page reloads properly. Please help.

I have added parts of the code in my main.js

```
<head> <body onload="beforeStartDeviceManagement();" onbeforeunload="beforeCloseWindow();"> </head>

function beforeCloseWindow() {
        // apply to 8000 or CB
        if (theDevice.is8k != undefined || theDevice.isVSP != undefined) {
            var vrfCheck = self.name.indexOf(vrfContextView.PrefixName);
            if (vrfCheck >= 0) {
                var idStr = self.name.substring(vrfCheck + vrfContextView.PrefixName.length);
                var id = parseInt(idStr);
                window.opener.closeVrfWindow(id);
            } else {
                if (window.isVrfWindowOpened()) {
                    window.closeVrfWindow(theView.vrfId);                   
                }
                if(window.helpPopup){
                    helpPopup.close();
                }
                if(window.theHelpWindow){
                    theHelpWindow.close();
                }
                // call save configugation function
                theView.validateSaveConfig();
            }
        }
        // else, do nothing
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are making a POST request to your current url, that's why it cannot be refreshed. Maybe your login form is sending it? With extjs you usually should be making ajax calls and redirects if needed, not regular form POST requests.

Comment: Like serg said, it looks like the current view is based on a (standard) POST request which was fired before.